# would parallel crypto mining work

Tags: hash, cryptocurrency, hash-tree

Hi everyone I was wondering would it be possible to mine a cryptocurrency like bitcoin in parallel. I have read a little about mining pools https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mining_pool , But that's not quite what I'm looking for . the idea i had was to create a customized mining software that would Comprise of a master node with multiple Slave nodes like this .
[image]

The master node would join the most profitable bitcoin mining pool
so let's say i had the slave software running on 20,000 computer.
The mining pool would see is one miner from me is this practical.

Comment: im not sure if this it the right place for my question

Comment: This is not the right place. Crytomining is typically performed in parallel, thus the answer to the question is a clear yes. Before planning for cryptomining, think twice about the carbon footprint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is called proxy mining, and it exists. You basically start your "own" pool, and let your master divide the work.

It's mostly done to have less load on the pool though, it has no computational advantage over having all slaves join the pool.